# Github PAT creation triggers 2 emails, is it a security issue?

Tags: github, github-enterprise

I am receiving 2 emails about the creation of PAT, is it a security vulnerability? or a Bug?

Note: I have 2 emails attached to my GitHub account (both emails configured to same mailbox, means those are alias emails) and we use  GitHub Enterprise Server (not cloud)

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution, it's a feature, by default security-relevant mails are sent to backup email Id, it can be changed in profile -> Email -> Backup Email Address.

GHES version: 3.2.9

Adding it as this may help someone. Have a nice day.